# Javascript Proper Referencing of Values

Tags: javascript, variables, reference

I have a global var that is updated later on in my program, and a previous variable set that that global var uses the original referenced value.

To illustrate,

```
var testVar = 1;

var hash = { 
    test : { 
        testGetVar : {opacity: testVar},
        testGetVarFn : function(){ return {opacity: testVar}; }
    }
}

testVar = 2;
console.log(hash.test.testGetVar.opacity); // returns 1
console.log(hash.test.testGetVarFn().opacity); //returns 2
```

Would someone clarify the proper way to do this?
Let's say if I had 10 objects in hash that uses testVar, would I have to write fn to get the updated value?

EDIT: 
I've changed some requirements and made my example to specific to my cause.

Here's getter/setter methods, but doesn't work.

```
var testVar = new Field("123");

function Field(val){
        this.value = val;
}
Field.prototype = {
        get value(){
             return this._value;
    },
        set value(val){
             this._value = val;
    }
};

var hash = { 
    test : { 
        testGetVar : {opacity: testVar.value} ,
        testGetVarFn : function(){ return testVar.value; }
    }
}

testVar.value = "abc";
console.log(hash.test.testGetVar.opacity); // returns 123
console.log(hash.test.testGetVarFn()); //returns abc
```

My assumption is that since the get method called when creating the hash, it stores the reference to that value at that time, thus will never return the updated value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could turn testVar into an object, because objects are passed by reference in js, this way you would not need to call a function to get the latest value:

```
var testVar = {'value':123};

var hash = { 
    test : { 
        testGetVar : testVar,
        testGetVarFn : function(){ return testVar; }
    }
}

testVar.value='abc';
console.log(hash.test.testGetVar.value); // returns 123 (not anymore: returns "abc" now)
console.log(hash.test.testGetVarFn().value); //returns abc
```

Comment: You mean to put, in you're console.log's respectively, `hash.test.testGetVar.value` and `hash.test.testGatVarFn().value`. It returns `[object Object]` for both in your version.

Comment: What if I needed the value inside the testGetVar object? like testGetVar : {opacity: testVar.value}

Comment: Sure you can do this, just use `console.log(hash.test.testGetVar.opacity);` then

Comment: But, stewe that returns me 123 instead.

Comment: You could use `testGetVar : {opacity: testVar}` and `console.log(hash.test.testGetVar.opacity.value)` but that's getting ugly..

Comment: You should not use global variables for that, have a look at: http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/

Comment: I've tried getter and setter methods, seems like same result. I've updated the question

Answer (score 2):

I think you are asking how to copy a reference to an integer.  Javascript doesn't support pointers, so I believe it can only be done in a closure such as the function in your example.  Note however that objects are by default passed by reference.

There is a good description of the by-value / by-reference rules when passing arguments here:

http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/web/jscript/ch09_03.html

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = "Hello",
    b = a;

a = "Goodbye";

console.log(b); // "Hello"
```

Since you're calling the function it will look for the latest version of `testVar`. The property `testGetVar` is given a value that will stay the same unless changed later on in the program. So yes, you will either have to explicitly update the value of `hash.test.testGetVar` or just call the function `testGetVarFn`.

Comment: So i have to write a function everytime to get the latest value?

Comment: Check the edit: yes, or update the value of `hash.test.testGetVar` on your own.